# How can I create a horizontal form in Semantic UI?

Tags: semantic-ui

I see there are horizontal examples in Bootstrap (`form-horizontal`), but Semantic UI only seems to have form layouts where the label is above the input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the docs section, You can find [**Semantic UI form inline**](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/form.html#inline) and [**Grouped fields**](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/form.html#grouped-fields) which is similar to form-horizontal of Twitter Bootstrap.

To create a new row of fields inside the form, wrap the elements inside `<div class="inline field"> </div>`

```css
/* Code added for presentation in SO snippet, ignore this CSS */

* > div,
h1 {
  margin-left: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.3/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h1>Single</h1>
<div class="ui form">
  <div class="inline field">
    <label>Last name</label>
    <input placeholder="Full Name" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="inline field">
    <label>Last name</label>
    <input placeholder="Full Name" type="text">
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Grouped</h1>

<div class="ui form">
  <div class="inline fields ui grid container centered">
    <label class="four wide column">Lengthy Phone numbers</label>
    <div class="field four wide column">
      <input type="text" placeholder="(xxx)">
    </div>
    <div class="four wide column field">
      <input type="text" placeholder="xxx">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="inline fields ui grid container centered">
    <label class="four wide column">Phone Number</label>
    <div class="four wide column field">
      <input type="text" placeholder="(xxx)">
    </div>
    <div class="field four wide column">
      <input type="text" placeholder="xxx">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I have seen the horizontal field before, but how can you apply it to a whole form so that the fields are all aligned in the correct column?

Comment: Can you show a bootstrap example that you are trying to create in semantic UI?

Comment: Lets say you have 2 fields, one below the other.  Here is an example: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Comment: You just need to create another div with `inline fields`. Check out the code I edited just now.

Comment: Ok it's almost looking right, except when the width of a label changes, none of the inputs are aligned anymore.  How would you get it to align all inputs to the same column (x)?

Comment: It is because column grid is not yet specified: http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#column-widths In the bootstrap example you have mentioned, it already has grid classes assigned to label. Check out my latest edit.

Comment: Thanks bro Hari, been addicted to SO much! :D

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the solution, i.e. class="inline field" does not work if the labels have different width, also the labels are not right-aligned as in the bootstrap example. One could solve this like this

```
<div class="inline field">
  <label style="width:30%; text-align:right;">Last name</label>
  <input placeholder="Full Name" type="text">
</div>
```

But that's ugly.